# Webpack babel transpile to es5 doesn't quite work

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, ecmascript-5, transpiler

I'm trying to build my ES7 source code into a single file and have it transpiled down to ES5 but when I run webpack I still notice code like this in the built bundle

```
t.exports=class extends n(0).Component{title(){return this.constructor.name}}}
```

The export of the class means that something is not quite working, this is my relevant webpack config

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["env"]
          }
        }
      },
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your .babelrc look like?

Comment: @James I don't have one, the env preset is said to convert ES5+ code to ES5 by default without any settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to save someone else the precious few hours I wasted - I was including libraries that contained ES5+ code from node_modules and as obvious as it is the config is ignoring node_modues, so I just had to remove that line.

Comment: Great! Using babel7 and webpack 4 the only way to make it work with IE11 is to remove this line. Infact, the problem is that it is sufficient that a single library has a ES5+ Es6 code that will make your bundle.js non ES5 compatible. I was looking for this tip since yesterday. Thanks!